# PHP: gzencode compression level

Tags: php

According to the [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php), `gzencode` supports a level of compression from 0-9.

I was wondering if someone wanted to compress something, doesn't it make sense to compress it as much as possible? Wouldn't you always want to set it at 9? Are there any drawbacks to always compressing at the maximum level possible?

Comment: The drawback may the the time it takes to compress it. The higher the compression, the longer it takes to process.

Comment: Better compression generally takes longer.  But this is a bit off topic for SO.

Comment: ... and when we say longer time we mean both in compressing and expanding.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález very good thing to mention, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> This comes at a cost of times. Compression is a CPU-intensive process,
>   and the more you compress a file, the longer it takes. Because of
>   this, gzip provides a range of compression levels from 1 to 9 in
>   `gzencode()` function.

1 gives the fastest compression speed but will compress at a lower rate, and 9 gives the highest compression ratio but at a lower speed.

*I have tried to give an example below to understand.*

```
// Initialize all required variables
$data = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/data.txt'); // which is big file data around 1MB.
$smallstring = "This is small string.";                     // small string to compress 
$array = array(
    'Big data' => $data, 
    'Small data' => $smallstring,
);

// Calling gzencode() with various compression levels
foreach ($array as $key => $string){
    echo "{$key} :\t Size = ".strlen($string). "\n";
    echo "level\t\tMD5\t\t\t\t\tTime\t\n";
    for($i = -1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $start_time = microtime(true); // store time before compress 
        $output     = gzencode($string, $i, FORCE_GZIP); // string wll compress here in diffrebnt level
        $end_time   = microtime(true); // store time after compress

        echo "$i\t".md5($output). "\t" . ($end_time - $start_time)."\tms\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

*This will generate the output as follows*

```
Big data :   Size = 1380637
level       MD5                            Time 
-1  ad730951a0cde5a05e152f40d4f6fe4a    0.01400089263916    ms
0   c7d8e4e6a5dbd82a73128f83ee2fc633    0.0069999694824219  ms
1   84d2229ad05877d2d54b0282a6cca0bf    0.0070009231567383  ms
2   ccab12e8b54ccf9e656badf4817e4959    0.0069999694824219  ms
3   f35b1091dc56c82c58618acbc553bdd4    0.007000207901001   ms
4   e515e7db5b16602143fec52da223762f    0.012000799179077   ms
5   4da249e96fccc7483f68044443ae819a    0.012001037597656   ms
6   ad730951a0cde5a05e152f40d4f6fe4a    0.01200008392334    ms
7   ad730951a0cde5a05e152f40d4f6fe4a    0.012001037597656   ms
8   729ecc80e4dd83b81d22eb652e870378    0.012001037597656   ms
9   5dba04d7f529c897c908526553c2cbde    0.012001037597656   ms

Small data :     Size = 21
level       MD5                         Time    
-1  d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
0   7f8375c3cf1a8841e1c7b66be0f8690f    0   ms
1   bc5c0ee1059ec442789cdd4361501cb2    0   ms
2   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
3   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
4   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
5   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
6   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
7   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
8   d7263212e7a0f6ca6bf44f2b31ffecdb    0   ms
9   ea6f5c64dffa44254db7327289f9a248    0   ms
```

As you can see in the above output, it takes different time at different levels with the same data string.
But when you use small data, it will take the same amount of time for all levels, as you can see.

75% of websites and almost all modern and new browsers and web servers support GZip. The whole process is transparent to the user, fast enough to run on almost any device, and in some cases can reduce resource size by 72%.